# Removing empty string from a list

Tags: python

From the below list, I want to remove empty lines (empty quotes followed by a newline char).

```
mylist =['',
         'advice talk neighbours family exchange',
         'dedicated shopping hours amid outbreak',
         '',
         'mar russia consumer surveillance watchdog reported case high',]
```

So desired output should be:

```
mylist =['advice talk neighbours family exchange',
 'dedicated shopping hours amid outbreak', 
 'mar russia consumer surveillance watchdog reported case high',]
```

I tried

```
text = os.linesep.join([s for s in mylist])
```

But above line of code combines all the lines by removing new-line character(s). My intended o/p is, it should only delete empty line(s) i.e. empty line with single quotes followed by new-line. All other non-empty strings along with its new-line char, should be retained.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean this? `[s for s in mylist if s]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mylist = [x for x in mylist if x!= '']
```

Comment: This will not work, I tried it, because it not just empty string, but empty string followed by newline char. That should be deleted from the list.

Comment: @Sri None of the strings in your question end with newline characters

Comment: @Sri Technically, if you have a newline character in your string, then it isn't empty.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have "lines" in your strings (`\n` characters).

There is no difference in a list like this

```
x = ['1', '2', '3']
```

And this

```
x = ['1', 
'2', 
'3',]
```

---

This is enough to remove *falsy* (i.e. empty) strings *and* strings of all whitespace

```
[s for s in mylist if s.strip()]
```

---

If you did have line-ending characters, see this example

```
mylist =['',
         'advice talk neighbours\nfamily exchange'
]

output = []
for s in mylist:
  if s.strip():
    output.extend(line for line in s.splitlines())

print(output)
# ['advice talk neighbours', 'family exchange']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
mylist = list(filter(None, mylist))
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me.

```
mylist =['',
         'advice talk neighbours family exchange',
         'dedicated shopping hours amid outbreak',
         '',
         'mar russia consumer surveillance watchdog reported case high']

text = [s for s in mylist if s != '']

print(text)
```

The output is:

```
['advice talk neighbours family exchange', 'dedicated shopping hours amid outbreak', 'mar russia consumer surveillance watchdog reported case high']
```